# How to continue data driven coded UI test even after fail

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I am doing data driven coded UI test. I have given 10 sets of data. It is failing at 5th data set and is stopping. I need Coded UI tests to continue data driven even after failure.
Please suggest me some way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your test please use this

Playback.PlaybackSettings.ContinueOnError = true;

Answer (score 0):

Put each set of data in a try-catch block. Catch the error and ignore it or handle it manually, then continue. I assume you pass your data to the UIMap. If so, then something like this:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test_Transaction_ID_67890_Test()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < testCaseList.Count; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                this.UIMap.ClickonManage(testCaseList);
                this.UIMap.ClickonAdd(testCaseList);
                this.UIMap.SelectAssigned(testCaseList);
                this.UIMap.SelectTransactionDateTime(testCaseList);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                TestContext.WriteLine(Got An Error On Iteration " + i.ToString() + "."; 
                TestContext.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }
```